# Extract only characters from a string and store it in another string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String, say

```
String str = "1.) Java is fun. play with 12"
```

I want everything after `)` to be stored as separate String. What is the best way to do it? I tried spliting the string on `")"`:

```
String det[] = str.split(")");
```

But it is giving:

> java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')'`

Sample input:

```
String str = "1.) JAVA is fun.Play with 12"
```

Sample output:

```
String result = "JAVA is fun.Play with 12"
```

Comment: String det[] = str.split(")");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`String.split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) takes a regex as parameter. `)` is a special character for regural expressions so you need to escape it with `\`. Since in Java `\` also needs to be escaped, you need to split with `\\)`.

```
String str = "1.) Java is fun. play with 12";
String[] tokens = str.split("\\)", 2); // split only in 2 parts
System.out.println(tokens[1]);
```

Note that in this code, I specified a limit of 2 to the `split` call. This means that it will split the String in 2 parts only. This is to tackle the case where the String you want to extract might also contain a `)`, like an input of `"1.) Java is fun :). Play with 12"`.

As a side note, in this case, it would be easier (and perhaps faster) to use `substring` instead of `split`, like this:

```
String str = "1.) Java is fun. play with 12";
String result = str.substring(str.indexOf(')') + 1);
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to split in this way.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  String s = "1.) Java is fun. play with 12";
  String[] r = s.split("\\)");
    for (int i = 0; i<r.length; i++){
        System.out.println(""+r[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked. My bad :P Will accept the answer in few minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

I will do something like this:

```
String str= "1.) JAVA is fun.Play with 12";
String separateString;
int index = str.indexOf(')');
if (index >= 0) {
    separateString = str.substring(index);
}
```